# Как вписать в бат файл %

Tags: bat

Например, мне надо вывести 5%5, как можно вывести данную надпись?(echo знаю) вопрос в том, как вывести %

Comment: `Echo 5^%5`, собсно...

Comment: что-то не идет(

Comment: В батч-файле знак процента следует удвоить, т.е. `echo 5^%%5`.

Comment: спасибо, все заработало